# Change value of SVG based on XPath in XSLT

Tags: xml, svg, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to generate HTML from XML with XSLT and I would like to include SVG on each page with appropriate colours that I pick with XPath from said XML doc.

However I'm having trouble with applying the template, as I don't know how to pass the xsl:variable into it.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document(concat(cfg:a/cfg:b, cfg:c))"/>
```

This code puts SVG file into my generated HTML.
I'd like to change some of the SVG like this

```
<rect x="1" y="163"
      width="119.5" height="52"
      rx="5" fill="$modsVar"/>
```

So the value of modsVar would change based on my XPath. Is that possible? Thanks!!!

Comment: Please share the svg-source

Comment: SVG is generated code from http://www.keyboard-layout-editor.com/
I'm basically trying to colour individual keys based on hex values in my XML.

Here is the code itself : https://pastebin.com/zmmNHn5Q

I was in the middle of trying to replace the {$barvaModsVar} with XSLT but I have limited knowledge of the subject.

Comment: It is not clear in which context you use XSLT, which version you use, whether that snippet shown with `$modsVar` or that comment with `{$barvaModsVar}` is some attempt to use XSLT variable references or some fragment from another language. So perhaps, even if your aim is to solve the problem for the big file you have linked to, try to reduce it to a specific question with small but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you want and the one you get, plus the XSLT processor you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have e.g. `<xsl:param name="modsVar" select="foo/bar/baz"/>` or `<xsl:variable name="modsVar" select="foo/bar/baz"/>` in your XSLT, then of course a literal result element `<rect x="1" y="163" width="119.5" height="52" rx="5" fill={"$modsVar}"/>` will create a `rect` element where the `fill` attribute has a value taken from the value bound to `modsVar`, i.e. the evaluation of the XPath expression `foo/bar/baz`.